# MySQL Conditional Insert. Works in phpMyAdmin but not PHP Script

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, mysql-error-1062

I am trying to create a conditional INSERT into my MySQL databate from a PHP script.  The following SQL syntax works in phpMyAdmin, but not in my PHP Script:

```
INSERT INTO profiles (id, firstname)
SELECT "22","John" from profiles
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM li_profiles
WHERE li_p_firstname = "John"
)
```

(Note that "id" is the primary key, "firstname" is not a key or unique)

Something weird that might be part of the issue is that when I run that SQL in phpMyAdmin, while it does "work" (meaning that a new record is added with the id "22" and the firstname "John") I get the following warning: "#1062 - Duplicate entry '22' for key 1"
But the table didn't have a previous entry with id of 22.  ??!!

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Change SELECT to VALUES

```
INSERT INTO profiles (id, firstname) VALUES("22","John") FROM profiles WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM li_profiles WHERE li_p_firstname = "John" )
```

Also, if you are using auto-increment values, you should specify the next value. Also, if its an integer, give an integer (22) not a string ("22")

Comment: Thanks, Seth.
Unfortunately, it still doesn't work.  Making that switch gives me this error in phpMyAdmin:

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM profiles WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM li_profiles WHERE li_p_firstname ' at line 5.

Line 5 is "From profiles".  Because I took out select, I think FROM doesn't belong anymore.  It also doesn't work if I take out "FROM profiles".

Any other ideas?

Comment: Seth, I figured out a different way to do it.  Thanks for finding my integer in quotes, though.  Saved me some future headaches.

Comment: sorry, your answer is wrong. `insert into table select a, b from table` is valid MySQL syntax and sometimes very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get a duplicate entry for the iD because you are inserting a new row for each row in the `profiles` table; for every row in the `profiles` table there is no John in the `li_profiles` table. You might try

```
INSERT INTO profiles (id, firstname)
    SELECT "22","John" from profiles
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM li_profiles
                              WHERE li_p_firstname = "John")
        LIMIT 1;
```

which would eliminate the duplicate problem (if it works, sorry but I haven't checked this myself).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out in a different way.  (I'm told that the HAVING statement is slow, so I'm not sure that it's the best way... but it the only method I've gotten to work.)

```
INSERT INTO profiles (id,firstname)
SELECT 22,'John'
FROM li_profiles
WHERE firstname = 'John'
HAVING COUNT(*) = 0;
```

Comment: This query doesn't do that much: it just inserts "22", "John" into the table if it does not exist already. If it's that that you want, try `INSERT IGNORE (id, firstname) VALUES (22, "John")` - that way you're not writing a SELECT where none is needed.

Comment: Sorry, Konerak.  I mis-wrote the code in my answer.  I want to insert a record in a certain table if certain values do not exist in a DIFFERENT table.  I just edited my answer to reflect that.  Given that, is there a more efficient way than using "Having"?